# RDD.distinct() ++ RDD will make the processs not stop

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Here is a request in the data process, AlertRDD is used to produce unique alerts count and not unique alerts count for one day.
So I write below method include both two of them,

```scala
implicit class RDDOps(val rdd: RDD[(String, String)]) {
  def addDistinctRDD() = {
    rdd.distinct().map{
      case (elem1, elem2) =>
        (elem1, elem2, "AlertUniqueUsers")
    } ++ rdd.map{
      case (elem1, elem2) =>
        (elem1, elem2, "Alerts")
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `AlertRDD.addDistinctRDD.save(//path)`, the program will never stop, but if run it as as `AlertRDD.cache.addDistinctRDD.save(//path)`, it works well.

Could anybody know the reason?

**Update**

It looks like nobody can answer my question, probably my question is not well understood.

Why I add **unique** AlertRDD and **non-unique** AlertRDD together?
Because the follow-up process of two RDDs is the same, Something like below excerpt code:

```
 .map((_, 1))
 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
 .map()
 ....
 .save($path)
```

If my solution is not the good one, can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: what is that `(elem1,elem1 "AlertUniqueUsers")` is there a typo ?

Comment: and your codes compile ? how do you keep the information during runtime ?

Comment: keep what infomation?

Comment: sorry *type* information.

Comment: ok, update more clear